# Deserialization with Jackson: "org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of [projectname]."

Tags: java, javascript, jersey, sencha-touch-2, jackson

I'm working on a **RESTful** app based on [this tutorial](http://miamicoder.com/sencha-touch-tutorials/) (wich is just a simple webapp about notes without any webservice by default).

Unfortunately, when i try to add a note, there is no errors on the first time and the note is really saved in my arrayList of a singleton server-side. No errors...

But when I retry to add an other note, it fails with this error in my jetty server console:

```
janv. 24, 2014 7:54:29 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException
Grave: The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of [...].noteapp.rest.model.Note out of START_ARRAY token
at [Source: org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInput@71453e59; line: 1, column: 1]
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:163)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.mappingException(StdDeserializationContext.java:219)
```

A weird thing is that if I reload the page, it works again one time.

---

Here is the Sencha **model** of my notes (model.Note.js):

```
Ext.define("NotesApp.model.Note", {
    extend: "Ext.data.Model",
    config: {
        idProperty: 'id',
        fields: [
            { name: 'id', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'dateCreated', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'U' },
            { name: 'title', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'narrative', type: 'string' }
        ],
        validations: [
            { type: 'presence', field: 'id' },
            { type: 'presence', field: 'dateCreated' },
            { type: 'presence', field: 'title', message: 'Veuillez entrer un titre pour cette note' }
        ]
    }
});
```

---

Here is the **storage** (store.Notes.js):

```
Ext.define("NotesApp.store.Notes", {
    extend: "Ext.data.Store",
    config: {
        autoLoad: true,
        model: "NotesApp.model.Note",
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: '/restnotes/notearray',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'note'
            },
            writer: {
                type: 'json',
                writeAllFields: true
            },
            actionMethods: {
                read: "GET",
                create: "POST",
                update: "POST",
                destroy: "DELETE"
            },
            api: {
                read: 'restnotes/notearray/arraynotes',
                create: 'restnotes/notearray/note',
                update: 'restnotes/notearray/note',
                destroy: 'restnotes/notearray/note'
            },
            id: 'notes-app-store'
        },
        sorters: [
            { property: 'dateCreated', direction: 'DESC'}
        ],
        grouper: {
            sortProperty: "dateCreated",
            direction: "DESC",
            groupFn: function (record) {

                if (record && record.data.dateCreated) {
                    return record.data.dateCreated.toDateString();
                } else {
                    return '';
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

---

Here is the part of the **ctrl** where I add a note to the storage (controller.Notes.js):

```
onNewNoteCommand: function () {

    console.log("onNewNoteCommand");

    var now = new Date();
    var noteId = (now.getTime()).toString() + (this.getRandomInt(0, 100)).toString();


    var newNote = Ext.create("NotesApp.model.Note", {
        id: noteId,
        dateCreated: parseInt(now.getTime()/1000),
        title: "",
        narrative: ""
    });

    this.activateNoteEditor(newNote);

},

[...]

onSaveNoteCommand: function () {

    console.log("onSaveNoteCommand");

    var noteEditor = this.getNoteEditor();

    var currentNote = noteEditor.getRecord();
    var newValues = noteEditor.getValues();

    // Update the current note's fields with form values.
    currentNote.set("title", newValues.title);
    currentNote.set("narrative", newValues.narrative);

    var errors = currentNote.validate();

    if (!errors.isValid()) {
        Ext.Msg.alert('Wait!', errors.getByField("title")[0].getMessage(), Ext.emptyFn);
        currentNote.reject();
        return;
    }

    var notesStore = Ext.getStore("Notes");

    if (null == notesStore.findRecord('id', currentNote.data.id)) {
        notesStore.add(currentNote);
    }

    notesStore.sync();

    notesStore.sort([
        { property: 'dateCreated', direction: 'DESC'}
    ]);

    this.activateNotesList();
},
```

---

Here is my **java bean** (Note.java):

```
@JsonAutoDetect
@JsonDeserialize()
public class Note {

    private String id;
    private long dateCreated;
    private String title;
    private String narrative;


    @JsonCreator
    public Note(@JsonProperty("id") String id, @JsonProperty("dateCreated") Date dateCreated, @JsonProperty("title") String title, @JsonProperty("narrative") String narrative) {
        System.out.println("Il passe dans le constructeur JSON lors de la création dans sencha");
        this.id = id;
        this.dateCreated = dateCreated.getTime();
        this.title = title;
        this.narrative = narrative;
        System.out.println(this.toString());
    }

    public Note(String id, long dateCreated, String title, String narrative) {
        System.out.println("Il passe dans le constructeur normal");
        this.id = id;
        this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
        this.title = title;
        this.narrative = narrative;
        System.out.println(this.toString());
    }
    [...all getter-setters and else...]

}
```

I don't give the controller of the server that add the note send in JSON to the arraylist because the error is not there (i debugged it and the error seems to be client-side)

I searched a lot of time about this error and I tried a lot of solutions but nothing worked.

I hope you can help me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem.
When I `sync()` my storage, it sends everything because I didn't set the old notes as `currentNote.dirty = false`. It was in my **controller.Notes.js**, so after I sync, I set `currentNote.dirty = false`:

```
notesStore.sync();

currentNote.dirty = false;

//Tri des notes
notesStore.sort([
    { property: 'dateCreated', direction: 'DESC'}
]);

this.activateNotesList();
```

And then it works because Sencha only send one object every time.